# Can not go to specific endpoind at spring boot, It redirects to login,

Tags: spring-boot

I want to go the URL. It is

`localhost:8090/it/add-edit`

But it redirects to login just like i am not logged in.

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8090/it/add-edit
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302
```

This is the controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/it")
public class UserController  {

//    @PreAuthorize("@customPermissionEvaluator.hasAuthority()")
    @GetMapping(value = {"/add-edit"})
    public ModelAndView getSaveUserView() {

        ModelAndView modelView = prepareModel("add-edit");


        modelView.addObject("allUserNamesIdsList", service.findAllUserNamesAndIdsList());


        return modelView;
    }
```

And this is the **configuration**:

```
  http
                    .cors()
                .and()
                  .csrf()
                .disable();

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(resources).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(
                     "/login**"
            )
            .anonymous()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .
```

.
.

And this is another controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/fraud")
@PreAuthorize("@customPermissionEvaluator.hasAuthority()")
public class FraudController  {

    @GetMapping("/fraud")
    public ModelAndView fraudHome(
            ) {
```

I can go here without any problem.

But i cant go any endpoints under `it`. Such as `/it/add-edit`

Note: There are other controllers who also has `it` has main mapping. I also closed other controllers who has `it` but still did not work.

But when i change name of `it`, it works.

I mean, from all controllers, I changed `it` to `itf` and it still worked. So, it is about **it**.

So `/itf/add-edit` is working.

Why is `it` blocked?

It was working before. I do not know what I changed.

Comment: It sounds like that there is another web filter or something else to block your request with context root `/it`.

Comment: @LHCHIN there is no filter. There is only `PreAuthorize` but i commented it :(

Comment: Have you tried change @GetMapping(value = {"/add-edit"}) to @GetMapping("add-edit") ?

Comment: @MuriloGóesdeAlmeida yes. also tried converting to `requestmapping`